# How to remove null values from array containing array

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have an array like this

```
String arr[][] = {{"abc"}, {"bcd"}, {null}}
```

This is multi dimensional array (single string array with in an array). I want to remove those nulls and want final result as `{{"abc"}, {"bcd"}}`. This array could be of any size and there can any number of nulls

I tried something like this. I know I can use traditional for loops, but I want to do it using java8 or more efficiently.

```
 String arr1[][] = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .filter(str -> (((str != null) && (str.length > 0))))
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I edited the my question @Naman

Comment: Not exactly if you look at the braces @Muntasir

Comment: By the way, you should avoid writing arrays like this: `String arr1[][]`, you should write `String[][] arr1` instead, for the brackets actually belong to the type, rather than the variable name. The reason it is legal in Java is probably because it is an artifact from C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use streaming from `Arrays` helper class an filter non-null values:

```
String arr[][] = {{"abc"}, {"bcd"}, {null}};

String result[][] = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(innerArray -> Arrays.stream(innerArray).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Edit:

As @Andreas pointed out, this leaves empty inner arrays, we need to filter them with additional `filter(innerArray -> innerArray.length > 0)`. Finally:

```
String result[][] = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(innerArray -> Arrays.stream(innerArray).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new))
    .filter(innerArray -> innerArray.length > 0)
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Comment: That produces `[[abc], [bcd], []]`, not the desired `[[abc], [bcd]]`

Comment: `NullPointerException` if input is e.g. `{{"abc"}, {"bcd"}, null}`

Comment: Yes, you're passing a null inner array, for `{{"abc"}, {"bcd"}, {null}}` it works fine. If you want possibility for null arrays, they would have to be filtered first or null check is needed.

Comment: Easy enough to add another `nonNull` filter before the `map(...)`.

Comment: That's right, `filter(Objects::nonNull)` before `map` would be sufficient. However I won't add it in my answer, as this is not the data in question and adding validation might make the code unreadable. Same thing would happen, when `arr == null`. But thank you for the discussion :)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for saving my day. Andronicus is right. I will never give this input {{"abc"}, {"bcd"}, null}.

Answer (score 0):

you're almost there with your solution; just one mistake with a check:

```
String arr1[][] = Arrays.stream(arr)
                        .filter(str -> str[0] != null)
                        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```